# How to save indexed color PNG in java

Tags: java, graphics, png, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

[image: This should have white background]How to save image in java as `java.awt.image.IndexColorModel` PNG? I'm loading indexed color png with ImageIO, manipulate it with *Catalino* library which unfortunately converts the color space to `java.awt.image.DirectColorModel`.

Now I want to save the result in the exactly same format as the original image. I tried the following snippet of code.

```
private static void testIndexedColor() throws IOException {
        FastBitmap input = new FastBitmap("test.png");
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(input.getWidth(), input.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED);
        bi.getGraphics().drawImage(input.toBufferedImage(), 0, 0, null);
        ImageIO.write(bi, "PNG", new File("test_result.png"));
}
```

But in the result weird light gray pixel artifacts appeared in the white background, and PPI decreased . How to correctly convert back to indexed color mode without quality loss and distortion?

Comment: What happens here, is that your `bi` `BufferedImage` is created with a default `IndexColorModel` (which happens to be the same colors as the 256 color "web-safe" palette). You need to get the `IndexColorModel` or the palette entries in some form, from `input`. If that's not possible, as a worst case you could read the input file again using `ImageIO` to get it (slower), or even re-create a "best" palette for the modified image using some form of color reduction (slowest). Not sure what happened with the PPI (or if that even matters).

Comment: PS: Is the library you are referring to, the *Catal**a**no* framework?

Comment: Also worth of mentioning, the particular image is black and white. When I open it in gimp mode says it's indexed color. However, if I load this image with ImageIO to BufferedImage and immediately write this same BufferedImage to file using ImageIO, the mode is mystically Grayscale now. I'm not even sure if Grayscale and indexed color are mutually exclusive or could grayscale image use palette? And why this conversion happens?

Comment: Would you mind sharing the PNG? In Java `IndexColorModel` always use sRGB color space. But that doesn't stop the colors from being all gray. So it really depends on what you define as "grayscale". Conversion typically happen (in Java ImageIO, I don't know the Gimp in this detail), when there's no `ColorModel` class that matches the color data in the file, or if such a `ColorModel` would be impractical (slow).

Comment: Did my updated version help you?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I'm correct about the Catalano framework, you should be able to re-write your methods as this:

```
private static void testIndexedColor() throws IOException {
    BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new File("test.png"));
    FastBitmap input = new FastBitmap(bi);

    Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
    try {
        g.drawImage(input.toBufferedImage(), 0, 0, null);
    }
    finally {
         g.dispose(); // Good practice ;-)
    }

    ImageIO.write(bi, "PNG", new File("test_result.png"));
}
```

At least you should get away with the fixed palette and the artifacts.

However, this will likely *still* modify the PPI (but this won't affect the pixels). And even in some cases the image might be written back as a non-palette PNG.

---

Update: It seems the `PNGImageWriter` (through the `PNGMetadata`) actually re-writes an `IndexColorModel` containing a perfect grayscale, to a grayscale PNG by default. This is normally a good idea, as you reduce file size by not writing the PLTE chunk. You should be able to get around this, by passing the metadata from the original, along with the image pixel data, to instruct the writer to keep the `IndexColorModel` (ie. write PLTE chunk):

```
private static void testIndexedColor() throws IOException {
    File in = new File("test.png");
    File out new File("test_result.png");

    try (ImageInputStream input = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(in);
         ImageOutputStream output = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(out)) {
        ImageReader reader = ImageIO.getImageReaders(input).next(); // Will fail if no reader
        reader.setInput(input);

        ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWriter(reader); // Will obtain a writer that understands the metadata from the reader
        writer.setOutput(output);  // Will fail if no writer

        // Now, the important part, we'll read the pixel AND metadata all in one go
        IIOImage image = reader.readAll(0, null); // PNGs only have a single image, so index 0 is safe

        // You can now access and modify the image data using:
        BufferedImage bi = (BufferedImage) image.getRenderedImage();
        FastBitmap fb = new FastBitmap(bi);

        // ...do stuff...

        Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
        try {
            g.drawImage(fb.toBufferedImage(), 0, 0, null);
        }
        finally {
            g.dispose();
        }

        // Write pixel and metadata back
        writer.write(null, image, writer.getDefaultWriteParam());
    }
}
```

This *should* (as a bonus) also keep your PPI as-is.

PS: For production code, you also want to `dispose()` of the `reader` and `writer` above, but I left it out to keep focus and avoid further discussion on `try/finally`. ;-)

Comment: I’m glad you added the `dispose()`, but the try-finally is not necessary.  It is almost impossible for `g.drawImage` to throw an exception.

Comment: @VGR It's necessary in cases where you run out of memory.

Comment: If you intend to “recover” from OutOfMemoryErrors (actually, you can’t), you might as well put every line of code in a try-finally.  When you run out of memory, program execution is effectively finished and the only useful action is to exit.

Comment: @VGR There's a reason the `dispose()` method's there in the first place. Normally, in Java, you'd let the GC handle this. But as native resources may be involved, you need the explicit `dispose()`. And that is also why you should have the `try/finally`. It's *not* about recovery. It's about releasing any resource you might hold onto (same as with stream's `close()` etc). I also disagree with the rest of your statement, but I won't go there... ;-)

Comment: I tested this, and result got saved in *Grayscale*. I asserted the `ColorModel` of `BufferedImage` is an instance of `IndexColorModel` after the `read` and `drawImage` operations. It seems like it's the `write` method which converts the `ColorModel`. Is it possible to bypass this?

Comment: @TuomasToivonen There might be a way. However, you really should share your PNG (any PNG that you can use to reproduce the issue will do), as I asked for in the comments. The above code worked for my test, probably because there's many ways to save a PNG.